# Controlling speed of animation via a selector form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make the speed of an animation selectable. I've written the following code but I cant work out whats stopping it from working. If I remove $("#speed").val(); and replace it with a value, it works fine. 
Any ideas will be greatly received!

```
<div class="lowerthird"> </div>

<button onclick="lowerthirdout();">Lower Third Out</button>

<select id="speed">
  <option value="1000">Fast</option>
  <option value="2000">Medium</option>
  <option value="5000">Slow</option>
  <option value="0">None</option>
</select>


function lowerthirdout(){

    var speed = $("#speed").val();

    $(".lowerthird").animate({ 
        left: "640px",
    }, speed );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is an extra comma after your 640px. also you need to make the number an int, not a string with parseInt:

http://jsfiddle.net/wpDdN/1/

```
function lowerthirdout(){

    var speed = parseInt($("#speed").val(), 10);

    $(".lowerthird").animate({ 
        left: "640px"
    }, speed );
}
```

Comment: @AdamMerrifield - A more simple way to turn a string into a number is `speed = +$("#speed").val()`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this
http://jsfiddle.net/E6FHC/